# Are questions about use of mobile apps on topic here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Are questions about use of mobile apps on topic here? Especially apps without readily available customer support? In particular I've got a non-platform-specific usage question about Uber.

Comment: @random Thanks. What if it's a non platform specific question about app usage? Sort of like questions about OpenOffice usage here, that aren't Linux, Windows or Mac specific. Are mobile apps generally treated a little differently than desktop apps?

Comment: Just pick one of the platforms and go for your choice of http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/, http://android.stackexchange.com/ or
http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If by "mobile" you simply mean multi-platform (Windows / Mac / Linux) then ask here. If you mean an cross-platform for mobile phones then it is off-topic here and should be asked on the site that is most relevant to your specific current needs for mobile devices as given by DavidPostill.

Comment: @Mokubai the "duplicating" question asking for software recommendations, not app configuring. The two may share the same answer, but they are still different ones. (I've should tag random, but I'm not sure if they are notified)

Comment: @Ooker I didn't close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Mokubai sorry, didn't mean to blame you on anything. I tag you because as a mod you can decide what this question should be by your own (any mod can do it either). But anyway, do you think that it's a dup?

Comment: @Ooker To be honest, yes. The other question is double sided and can be read both ways. Your answer there is fine, but this is still a dupe.

Comment: @Mokubai as in my comment there, I think the title is misleading and should be edited. After that, it's no longer double sided, and this question is no longer a dupe of it

Comment: @Ooker while the first line of the question mentions recommendations the rest of the question is quite specific: "So for mobiles, where can I ask questions? Does the Stack Exchange Network have any community for mobiles?"

Comment: @Mokubai imo, that first line shapes the main interest of the asker, and we should read the question that way. But now I can see that is one way to see that, and there are other ways (as how you see it). Thank you.

Comment: @Ooker Fwiw the duplicate link seems reasonable to me and contains the correct answer to my question as well. Plus it's not like either question is wildly popular, I'm sure the other 30 people who've seen this one in the last six months won't mind, ha.